# SELECT from table where a field does not exist in an item master table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an item master table in MSSQL that has SKUs and all Colors associated with a given SKU:

```
SKU | Color  
-----------
100 | BLK
100 | GRN
101 | RED
101 | BLU
101 | TAN
```

Then I have a MySql table with a similar structure, but it has Colors (by SKU) that do not exist in the item master table, and I need to delete them.
Here is what I have so far (note I use OPENQUERY to link the two tables):

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(WEB, '
     SELECT SKU, `Filename`, Color
     FROM IP24_Import_Images
') as B
INNER JOIN sap.ItemMasterSkuColor IM
ON B.SKU = IM.Sku
WHERE B.Color NOT IN (
    SELECT Color FROM sap.Item_Master_StyleColor
    WHERE Sku ....
```

I'm trying to select them first.. then I should be able to figure out how to delete them from there. But I get stuck at the end there..
Obviously `WHERE B.Color != IM.Color` will not work. The `NOT IN ..` I have above would work if I could somehow get the SKU in question from the outer query. How can I get this working properly? Thanks!

Comment: The title is misleading.  Appears you do not want to delete from table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you do somethign like

```
SELECT * 
FROM IP24_Import_Images B
LEFT JOIN sap.ItemMasterSkuColor IM
ON B.SKU = IM.Style AND B.Color = IM.Color
WHERE IM.Color IS NULL
```

should give you all records from IM and B.color is NULL if it is not matching.

I hope mySQL has the same syntax with right join as this one is MSSQL syntax.

Comment: On MSSQL you choose LEFT or RIGHT depending from which table you join want alle records, I guess it is the same on mySQL. But you right, ths has a logical problem regarding the number or records, I switch it (edit answer).

Comment: Ofc I modified there WHERE statement as well.